# How to remove custom marker from open street map and reload it again?

Tags: android, openstreetmap, marker

Here is my code. I can load marker using this method.But i want to load another marker at the same place, so i tried to remove older and put new one.

```
private void locationFind(String latitude, String longitude) {

                    Double latDouble = Double.parseDouble(latitudeStr);
                    Double lanDouble = Double.parseDouble(longitudeStr);

                    marker = new Marker(mapView, getContext());
                    marker.setPosition(new GeoPoint(latDouble - .001, lanDouble + .001));
                    marker.setIcon(new BitmapDrawable(createCustomMarker(1)));
                    marker.setAnchor(Marker.ANCHOR_CENTER, Marker.ANCHOR_BOTTOM);
                    mapView.getOverlays().add(marker);
                    marker.setOnMarkerClickListener(new Marker.OnMarkerClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker, MapView mapView) {
                            marker.closeInfoWindow();                                                              
                            return false;
                        }
                    });
                    mapView.getOverlays().add(marker);           
    }
}
```

Comment: googleMap.clear(); and add again

Comment: Try `mapView.getOverlays().remove(marker)` to remove the marker overlay, or remove all overlay objects with `mapView.getOverlays().clear()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in the same thread

mapView.getOverlayManager().clear() ;
MapView.invalidate();

Then add..